# In combat, what can change the order or value of initiatives?

Tags: dnd-5e, initiative

I'm wondering if there is something that can modify initiatives in combat, something like "Slow" or "Haste" spell (they do completely different things, though). I'm thinking something that can add +5 initiative to overtake certain character turn. It does not have to be a permanent modifier.

I'm aware that initiative was meant to be [rolled once and discarded](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/98532/40999). I also do not want the initiative for each creature to be re-rolled. Only modified.

Comment: Should I use [optional-rules] tag? Or [house-rules] tag?

Comment: Probably [tag:homebrew], but be aware that open-ended homebrew requests are off topic (not sure if this one is over the line or not).